# GAE Logs API (Python) - Requests to Static Handler Do Not Show Up

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I have a python Google App Engine app and I wish to query my server logs to get some insight about requests handled by the static file handler.

That is, I have a static handler serving images from a folder called /static:

from my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /static/*
  static_dir: static/
```

for this purpose I am trying to get the logs using logservice class (Logs API), which is documented nicely [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/).

long story short, this is my bit of code that fetches the logs:

```
start_time = time.time() - 86400
end_time = time.time()
for req_log in logservice.fetch(end_time=end_time,
                start_time=start_time,
                offset=None,
                minimum_log_level=None,
                include_app_logs=True):
                for app_log in req_log.app_logs:
                    result += ('<br />Message: %s<br />' % app_log)
```

The thing is, I am only getting logs for requests generated by the dynamic content handler. So while I am able to see logs for static requests in the GAE logs dashboard, and these requests are also accounted for when I download the logs using appcfg, they are not returned by the logservice.fetch metohd.

Is there a way around this bug/weird design decision? I do not want to download the file using appcfg, I want to access the logs programatically without having to deal with file download (this is what the Logs API is made for...).